# Hide Stepwise Regression in R

Tags: r

I was trying to hide the result of the stepwise regression so it won't appear on the terminal but it seems that invisible function won't work. Is there a way to hide stepwise regression result? Please refer to the dataset below

```
library(MASS)
all_df <- data.frame(x1=c(sample(rep(c(4:5),length.out=60)),sample(rep(c(1:3),length.out=40)),sample(rep(c(1:5),length.out=100))),
                     y1=c(sample(c(0,1), 30,replace=T,prob=c(.3,.7)),c(sample(c(0,1), 30,replace=T)),sample(c(0,1), 40,replace=T,prob=c(.7,.3))),
                     y2=c(sample(c(0,1), 30,replace=T,prob=c(.3,.7)),c(sample(c(0,1), 30,replace=T)),sample(c(0,1), 40,replace=T,prob=c(.7,.3))))


invisible(result_srk<- as.data.frame(summary( stepAIC(lm(x1~y1*y2
                                                         ,data=all_df), direction="both"))$coef))
```

Comment: Add `trace = 0` in `stepAIC`.

Comment: I don't see any ridge regression in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard method is to use sink():

```
sink(tempfile())
result_srk<- as.data.frame(summary( stepAIC(lm(x1~y1*y2,
     data=all_df), direction="both"))$coef)
sink()
```

Comment: No, the standard method is given in @Pascal's comment.